# havin issue when importing project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I could not import my project in android studio

```
Project is using an old version of the Android Gradle plug-in. The minimum 
           supported version is 0.6.1.
```

build.gradle
  i have tried like this.still getting error

```
  1) dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
}

    2)    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.3'
}

    3)  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.2'
}
  4)dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.1'
}
```